# VBA access run sql check row count

Tags: sql, vba

I'm trying to display a field on a form depending on the results of an sql query.  Since I don't know vba in access I'm struggling and don't know where I am going wrong.  Help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim RecordSt As Recordset
Dim dBase As Database
Dim stringSQL As String

Set dBase = CurrentDb()

stringSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 2"

DoCmd.RunSQL (stringSQL)

If RecordSt.Fields.Count > 0 Then
Me.Other.Visible = True
Else
Me.Other.Visible = False
End If
```

Comment: What is `RecordSt` ? Do you have an `Option Explicit` at the beginning of your module ? Couldn't you just use a `DCount()` here, eliminating the requirement for VBA code ?

Comment: 5 questions, only 1 with an accepted answer. No good replies for the 4 others ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If DCount("*", "table1", "id = 2") > 0 Then
   Me.Other.Visible = True
Else
   Me.Other.Visible = False
End if
```

or even quicker:

```
Me.Other.Visible = (DCount("*", "table1", "id = 2") > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems in your code.

First of all Docmd.RumSQL(stringSQL)
do not return nothing, and it is not related to your recordset RecordSt.

Also RecordSt.Fields.Count will count the FIELDS of your table and not the number of RECORDS selected.

This is a solution using ADODB. You probably have to add the reference to ADO (you can choose another version if you don't have 6.1) in your Tools->Reference menu from your VBA editor:

[image]

```
Dim rst As new ADODB.Recordset
Dim stringSQL As String

stringSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 2"

rst.Open SQL, CurrentProject.AccessConnection
If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Me.Other.Visible = True
Else
    Me.Other.Visible = False
End If
```

Comment: Can also be done using DAO, avoiding to add an external reference. The less they are, the better I feel :-)